# Securing J-Web interface with user lockouts after multiple bad login attempts

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos

I have a bit of an odd question that I can't seem to find much success in getting an answer via web searching.

I'm wondering if there is a way to secure the J-Web interface with user lockouts after multiple bad login attempts (similar to what can be achieved when accessing the CLI terminal via SSH or Telnet).

I have provided an example configuration for SSH to illustrate what I am trying to achieve for securing the J-Web interface.

```
system {
    login {
        retry-options {
            tries-before-disconnect 3;
            backoff-threshold 1;
            backoff-factor 5;
            lockout-period 1440;
        }
    }
    services {
        ssh {
            root-login allow;
            max-sessions-per-connection 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, I have found that a user locked out via terminal will not get locked out via J-Web. Which makes me feel like the web management portal probably runs on a completely different security model than the terminal.

I thought I would seek expert advice. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

> If it makes a difference, I am looking to configure this for our SRX series devices.

Comment: As the answer below hints, you should probably disable the HTTP access. That is an absolute requirement from our security team for any network infrastructure device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little reading documentation say we can limit on Juniper devices sessions and timeouts for sessions.
Check this documentation [there](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/operational/j-web-session-limits-setting.html)
But be aware this document mean that you use (v)SRX devices.

Also there is exist `lockout-period minutes;` 
see documentation [there](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/lockout-period-edit-system-login-retry-options.html) but yep it's not say that this option limit logins through all management services: ssh, telnet, web.

Even better solution: disable web management service

Also be good if you check documentation for your model of Juniper.

UPD:

[There similar question on the juniper forum dated 2015 year](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Limiting-login-retry-attempts/td-p/269678) 
There no similar limit for J-web as exist for ssh/telnet services.

So good way it's limit sessions and sessions timeouts, use https, setup ip's which acceptable to access management interfaces.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the answer I am looking for. I'm looking to configure the number of bad login attempts and set a lockout -- not to limit the number of sessions.

Comment: Also, the `lockout-period` (you noted as your second reference) is part of the same hierarchy I showed in my sample configuration `[edit system login retry-options]`. It does not apply to web (as you stated in your answer).

Comment: @Svek Be good if you say model of Juniper which you use.
I know that this not full answer, but point of start.

Comment: Good point. I did not state that I needed a configuration for an SRX series.

Comment: @Svek Please check my update.